# Calling the mocked object inside a for loop using easymock

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I have mocked an object using `Easymock.createNiceMock`.

```
MYRepository mockedMyRepository = EasyMock.createNiceMock(MyRepositoryWrapper.class);

EasyMock.expect(mockedRepository.findList(Asset.class, criteria)).andReturn(statusTypeList);
```

In the test class I have a for loop, inside which I call that `findList` method. It gets the value in the first loop but from the next one it returns `null`.

Even without a loop, only once it returns the value I specified.

```
System.out.println("first"+this.myRepository.findList(Asset.class).get(0)); \\ returns the correct value
System.out.println("second"+this.myRepository.findList(Asset.class).get(0)); \\ returns null
```

What is the solution here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
.anyTimes()
```

to the end of the expectation. So you get

```
EasyMock.expect(mockedRepository.findList(Asset.class , criteria)).andReturn(statusTypeList).anyTimes();
```

Otherwise, you are implicitly saying to expect it once only.

Comment: Thanks it worked! But I thought if I use createNiceMock then it won't make a problem and I can call it multiple times. Am I wrong?

Comment: See "nice mocks" here http://www.easymock.org/EasyMock3_0_Documentation.html. A nice mock gets default behavior for all its methods if you don't set any expectation. The default behavior is to return false, zero or null and allow you to call it any number of times. But you have overridden the default for this method by setting an expectation. That expectation includes an expected number of calls (one call by default).